# problema con cronometro en tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

hola estoy haciendo un programa con tkinter el cual tiene una barra de tareas el cual tiene 2 opciones las cuales son calcular y cronometro, si le das click a calcular te salira una sengunda ventana la cual es una calculadora la cual ya esta echa, en cambio si le das click a cronometro te salira un cronometro el cual estoy aun haciendo. El problema es con el cronometro que cuando lo ejecuto y le doy click al boton empezar me sale que 'time' no esta definidoy aun no se porque.

esto es lo que me sale:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\programa1\programa.py", line 108, in iniciar
    time['text'] = str(h)+":"+str(m)+":"+str(s)
NameError: name 'time' is not defined
```

aqui mi codigo:

```
from tkinter import *


window = Tk()

window.title("softnum")

window.geometry('900x800')
##########################funcion de calcular############################
def opcion1():
    ventanacalcular=Toplevel()
    ventanacalcular.geometry("700x600")
    from functools import partial
    import parser
    tecla1=Button(ventanacalcular, text="+",command=partial(click,"+"),height=3,width=6)
    tecla3=Entry(ventanacalcular,textvariable=texto_pantalla,width=50)
    tecla4=Button(ventanacalcular, text="x",command=partial(click,"x"),height=3,width=6)
    tecla5=Button(ventanacalcular, text="-",command=partial(click,"-"),height=3,width=6)
    tecla6=Button(ventanacalcular, text="÷",command=partial(click,"÷"),height=3,width=6)
    tecla7=Button(ventanacalcular, text="L",command=limpiar,height=3,width=6)
    tecla9=Button(ventanacalcular, text="1",command=partial(click, 1),height=3,width=6)
    tecla10=Button(ventanacalcular, text="2",command=partial(click, 2),height=3,width=6)
    tecla11=Button(ventanacalcular, text="3",command=partial(click, 3),height=3,width=6)
    tecla12=Button(ventanacalcular, text="4",command=partial(click, 4),height=3,width=6)
    tecla13=Button(ventanacalcular, text="5",command=partial(click, 5),height=3,width=6)
    tecla14=Button(ventanacalcular, text="6",command=partial(click, 6),height=3,width=6)
    tecla15=Button(ventanacalcular, text="7",command=partial(click, 7),height=3,width=6)
    tecla16=Button(ventanacalcular, text="8",command=partial(click, 8),height=3,width=6)
    tecla17=Button(ventanacalcular, text="9",command=partial(click, 9),height=3,width=6)
    tecla18=Button(ventanacalcular, text="0",command=partial(click, 0),height=3,width=6)
    tecla2=Button(ventanacalcular, text="resultado",command=operacion,height=3,width=9)
    
    
    tecla1.grid(column=3,row=9)
    tecla4.grid(column=5,row=9)
    tecla5.grid(column=6,row=9)
    tecla6.grid(column=7,row=9)
    tecla7.grid(column=2,row=9)
    tecla9.grid(column=1,row=10)
    tecla10.grid(column=2,row=10)
    tecla11.grid(column=3,row=10)
    tecla12.grid(column=8,row=10)
    tecla13.grid(column=4,row=10)
    tecla14.grid(column=5,row=10)
    tecla15.grid(column=6,row=10)
    tecla16.grid(column=7,row=10)
    tecla17.grid(column=8,row=4)
    tecla18.grid(column=9,row=12)
    tecla2.grid(column=5,row=2)
    tecla3.grid(column=5,row=1)
    
#funcion de def opcion1#
texto_pantalla=StringVar()

    
def click(num):
    texto_pantalla.set(texto_pantalla.get()+('*'if str(num)=='x' else '/' if str(num)=='÷' else str(num)))

def limpiar():
    global operador
    operador=("")
    texto_pantalla.set("")
    
def operacion():
    try:  
       ecuacion=str(eval(texto_pantalla.get()))
       texto_pantalla.set(ecuacion)      
    except:
        texto_pantalla.set("ERROR")

    


########################funcion de cronometro###########################  
def ventanacronometro():
    ventana2=Toplevel(window)
    ventana2.geometry("400x300")
    frame=Frame(ventana2)
    n1=Button(ventana2, text="empezar",command=iniciar)
    n2=Button(ventana2, text="detener",command=parar)
    n3=Button(ventana2, text="pausar")
    time = Label(ventana2,bg="black" ,fg='red', width=20, font=("","18"))
    time.pack()
    frame.pack()

   
    n1.place(x=15, y=13)
    n2.place(x=300, y=13)
    n3.place(x=160, y=90)  
    time.place(x=200,y=200)

##########################funcion de ventanacronometro#########################    
proceso=0

def iniciar(h=0, m=0, s=0):
    global proceso
 
    if s >= 60:
        s=0
        m=m+1
        if m >= 60:
            m=0
            h=h+1
            if h >= 24:
                h=0
 
   
    time['text'] = str(h)+":"+str(m)+":"+str(s)
 
    proceso=time.after(1000, iniciar, (h), (m), (s+1))
 
def parar():
    global proceso
    time.after_cancel(proceso)    

  

    
menubar = Menu(window)

filemenu = Menu(menubar,tearoff=0)


window.config(menu=menubar)
filemenu.add_command(label="calcular",command=opcion1)
filemenu.add_command(label="cronometro",command=ventanacronometro)

menubar.add_cascade(label="Archivo", menu=filemenu)


boton1 = Button(window, text ="min")
boton2 = Button(window, text ="hor")
boton3 = Button(window, text ="seg")

boton1.grid(column=2, row=0)
boton2.grid(column=3, row=0)
boton3.grid(column=4, row=0)

etiqueta1 = Label(window, text="hora de produccion")

etiqueta1.grid(column=0, row=0)

requisito1 = Entry(window,width=30)

requisito1.grid(column=1, row=0)

requisito2 = Entry(window,width=30)
etiqueta2 = Label(window, text="costo de materiales")
etiqueta2.grid(column=0, row=2)
requisito2.grid(column=1, row=2)

requisito3 = Entry(window,width=30)
etiqueta3 = Label(window, text="numero de empleados")

requisito3.grid(column=1, row=3)
etiqueta3.grid(column=0, row=3)

requisito4 = Entry(window, width=30)
etiqueta4 = Label(window, text="sueldo de empleados")

requisito4.grid(column=1, row=4)
etiqueta4.grid(column=0, row=4)

requisito5 = Entry(window,width=30)
etiqueta5 = Label(window, text="IVA")

requisito5.grid(column=1, row=5)
etiqueta5.grid(column=0, row=5)

requisito6 = Entry(window,width=30)
etiqueta6 = Label(window, text="precio: transporte")

requisito6.grid(column=1, row=6)
etiqueta6.grid(column=0, row=6)

window.mainloop()
```

si alguie sabe como ayudarme lo agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema se debe a que creas `time` dentro de la función `ventanacronometro`, pero como se trata de una variable local, queda dentro de la función. Eso significa que `time` es inexistente fuera de `ventanacronometro`.

Para solucionarlo, tenemos que hacer que la variable sea global (lo cual haces en otras partes del código). Siguiendo esta logica, el código de la función debería de quedar asi:

```
def ventanacronometro():
    #aqui hago global la variable time
    global time

    ventana2=Toplevel(window)
    ventana2.geometry("400x300")
    frame=Frame(ventana2)
    n1=Button(ventana2, text="empezar",command=iniciar)
    n2=Button(ventana2, text="detener",command=parar)
    n3=Button(ventana2, text="pausar")
    time = Label(ventana2,bg="black" ,fg='red', width=20, font=("","18"))
    time.pack()
    frame.pack()


    n1.place(x=15, y=13)
    n2.place(x=300, y=13)
    n3.place(x=160, y=90)  
    time.place(x=200,y=200)
```

*INFORMACION ADICIONAL:* `.pack`, `.grid` y `.place` son administradores de geometría separados. Su único propósito es ubicar widgets.
Cuando haces `time.pack()` ubicas el Label, pero cuando llamas a `time.place`, lo reubicas en las coordenadas indicadas.
Eso hace que el uso de `.pack` anterior sea redundante.